# Creating a model ChoiceField that relies on another model in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django but I'm trying to replace the categories constant with the types of videos from the other model, VideoTypes. How would I do this?

```
from django.db import models

# from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

# User = get_user_model()
CATEGORIES = (
    ('Executive Speaker Series', 'Executive Speaker Series'),
    ('College 101', 'College 101'),
    ('Fireside Chat', 'Fireside Chat'),
    ('Other', 'Other')
)


# Create your models here.
class VideoType(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.type

class Video(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORIES, max_length=255)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    # owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're looking for [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) field. It also needs to have set behaviour how it should behave when the related model is deleted, see [on_delete](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) description.

```
VideoType(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.type

class Video(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    category = models.ForeignKey(VideoType, on_delete=models.SET_NULL) # category is now referring to VideoType model
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The implementation that you have, requires tuples with variables instead of strings.

Change your `CATEGORIES` variable to

```
CATEGORIES = (
    (Executive_Speaker_Series, 'Executive Speaker Series'),
    (College_101, 'College 101'),
    (Fireside_Chat, 'Fireside Chat'),
    (Other, 'Other')
)
```